# How to get the spatial reference of table in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple SQL query that returns spatial results, how do I tell what the spatial reference is?

```
SELECT TOP 1000
    [OBJECTID], [test_ID], [Shape]
FROM 
    [spc].[gis_schema].[test]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
SELECT distinct SHAPE.STSrid
FROM [spc].[gis.schema].[test]
```

Returns the SRID 4326